# How to specify that Yum should not use proxy for specific domain

Tags: proxy, yum

Is it possible to specify domain for which yum should bypass proxy configuration ?
I'm afraid this is not possible...

I read that it was possible to use the environment variable `HTTP_PROXY` then `NO_PROXY`, is it the most elegant solution?

**[EDIT]**

I tried the solution with the environment variables:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@host:port
export http_proxy=http://user:pass@host:port
export no_proxy=.domain
export NO_PROXY=.domain
```

Yum uses proxy but the repos *.domain are not bypassed.

**[WORKAROUND]**

Using http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/ I can configure which domain should be ignore. But this wotks only with proxy that requires NTLM authentication...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I have not been able to get this to work using environment variables as you describe here. Yum does support proxies itself, however, and you should be able to do something like this:

```
proxy=http://proxy:port
```

Into `yum.conf` and then adding

```
proxy=_none_
```

Into the repo definitions you don't want to access via the global proxy. This is detailed (albeit succinctly) in the yum.conf man page.

Comment: Successful, finally. Thanks! I don't want to go through all the hosts again where I did it. But would it also be possible to add the proxy directly to these repo files where it is needed (e.g. all repos with external package servers, in contrast to the repo files that use internal package managers which don't need proxy)

Comment: `proxy=_none_` Brilliant, thanks. That is a ship load of awesome sauce. I'd up-vote you twice if I could :)

Comment: @erikbwork I just added a `proxy=http://proxy:port` to my .repo file and it worked. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 6):

If I understand this question correctly the desired behaviour is

*packages.centos.com* gets pulled via a proxy.

*packages.internal.lan* goes direct without going via the proxy.

I've just arrived here having googled how to do this myself, and used the above info to achieve what I wanted, however I'm not sure if the above answer is complete.

To do this I used the following.

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.internal.lan:port

export no_proxy=internal.lan

yum install package1 package2
```

*package1* got pulled from the internet via the proxy,

*package2* got pulled from my local mirror not going through the proxy.

Answer (score 5):

The replacement of yum on fedora is dnf.

For dnf `_none_` will cause an error

You'll need to set proxy to an empty string instead

```
proxy=
```

Reference: https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conf_ref.html

Comment: This is also true for CentOS 8!

Comment: Since `dnf` v4.2.11 (release Sep 2019) the use of `_none_` has been implemented for backwards compatibility (ref: https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf/commit/62c263452d5630b6605dc91c99469472b1390c35)

Answer (score 3):

My solution involves setting up Privoxy, a light http proxy.

> yum install privoxy

Add two forward clauses in /etc/privoxy/config :

```
 forward / myproxy.internal.lan:3128
 forward .internal.lan .
```

And also disable privoxy's default actions (ensure no header got corrupted) : (@line 175 in RHEL5 privoxy config)

```
#actionsfile standard  # Internal purpose, recommended
#actionsfile default   # Main actions file
#actionsfile user      # User customizations
```

Then setting up http_proxy and ftp_proxy environment variable to privoxy's port:

> declare -x http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8118
>
> declare -x ftp_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8118
>
> yum install package1 package2

Note: if you have proxy lines in yum.conf, remove it, it would override the environment variable.

Comment: I was looking for ways to whitelist hosts from privoxy and I've got my answer here :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just specify it in the repo file. For example:

```
[hduser@n0 cloudera-manager-installer]$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/cloudera-cdh4.repo  
[cloudera-cdh4]  
name=Cloudera's Distribution for Hadoop, Version 4  
baseurl=http://"yourhost"/cdh4/  
gpgcheck = 0
enabled=1
proxy=_none_
```

Answer (score 0):

proxy=*none* within repo definition didn't work on RHEL7.9,
it was still referring to the proxy specified in yum.conf,
but adding the specific proxy worked.
so in my case a specific outbound proxy which allows os updates is specified within yum.conf and have an internet enabled outbound proxy specified using proxy=http://proxy_ob:port within the specific repos

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something really new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.